# Width of Bootstrap Form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and I'm trying to increase the width of my form.

My form:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users" class="form-inline" role="form" id="new_user" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value=""></div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input autofocus="autofocus" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" name="user[email]" placeholder="Email" type="email" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div><input class="btn btn-default" name="commit" type="submit" value="Create my account"></div>
    </div>
    <br>
</form>
```

I've tried using the following style:

```
.form-inline .form-group input {
    width:440px;
}
```

However when I do this all my inputs including the Create My Account button increases its size along with all other inline-forms I have in my app.

Is there anyway possible to change the style for one single input in a particular form instead of all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a whole load of selectors, for example:

`.form-inline .form-group input[name=commit] { ... }`

`#new_user .form-group input:nth-child(1) { ... }`

There are many many more

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `col-*` on the `form-group`..

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users" class="form-inline" role="form" id="new_user" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value=""></div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
      <input autofocus="autofocus" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" name="user[email]" placeholder="Email" type="email" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div><input class="btn btn-default" name="commit" type="submit" value="Create my account"></div>
    </div>
    <br>
</form>
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/117635

Comment: when I trying using col-* the button is pushed to the right of the form as if the form is actually increasing however the form in reality does not.